# Ionic menu, how to avoid default adding of hide class for navicon icon

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a burger menu icon which serves as a toggle button in my header for a side menu. Since I have implemented a side menu, when I move from the front page where I have the header to some other page, if I go back to front page the navicon gets the class `hide` with `display:none`. 
Since I do want that burger menu to render I wonder how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

That will be set somewhere in your javascript, look through your main.js file or whichever you have set all your main functions in and look for wherever the page is set to autohide the menu burger bar.

If you can't find it I'd implement something along the lines of:

```
if (location == "home.html")
{
    $('.navicon').show();
}
else{
    $('.navicon').hide();
}
```

if this is at the bottom of your javascript file it should override the current setting. Also you will want jQuery for this otherwise you have to write.
`(document).getElementByClassName('navicon')`